airplane window topology
When I want to make the windows of the airplane, wrinkles are formed as in the picture. how can I do it without wrinkles suitable for topology?

File on Google Drive

if you use a Subdivision Surface modifier you could do a simpler topology. But maybe try to fix this one with a Shrinkwrap modifier? Could you please share your file?

If you use a Subdivision Surface modifier you could use a simpler topology like this one:


Thanks for sharing. I am already using subdivision surface. In the picture I shared, I already did as you did, doesn't it look like that? @moonboots
